# Quicktime server crash

Tags: xcode, macos, quicktime

I am using Xcode to create an Objective-C, cocoa, Mac app.

The application play movies from a play list in a loop.

```
movie1.mov,
movie2.mov,
movie3.mov,
...
movie1.mov,
movie2.mov,
movie3.mov,
...
and so on
```

The movies are loaded from file like this :

```
QTMovie* myMovie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:movieFilePath error:&error];
...
QTMovieView *movie_IBView;
...
[movie_IBView setMovie:myMovie];
...
[movie_IBView play:nil]; 
...
```

This works perfectly !

But after several hours movie stop playing and the QTMovieView remain desperately black !

The application isn't crashed but QuickTimeServer is crashed and the Console show the message bellow :

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, I don't know what is this 'objectForProxy'

Thanks

---

```
Process:         com.apple.qtkitserver [80994]
Path:            /System/Library/XPCServices/com.apple.qtkitserver.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.qtkitserver
Identifier:      com.apple.qtkitserver
Version:         1.0 (1)
Build Info:      QuickTime-2345000000000000~1
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2013-09-08 21:55:26.114 +0200
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[80994]: garbage collection is OFF
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'objectForProxy: proxy 0x6a36ed20 not found in hash table. aborting.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x912e1a67 __raiseError + 231
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x965a1149 objc_exception_throw + 155
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x91249289 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 137
    3   Foundation                          0x925d229e -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 101
    4   com.apple.qtkitserver               0x0002dcce objectForProxy + 236
    5   com.apple.qtkitserver               0x0002ed47 do_setMovie + 70
    6   com.apple.qtkitserver               0x00024603 _XsetMovie + 155
    7   com.apple.qtkitserver               0x00015aba QTKitServer_server + 160
    8   com.apple.qtkitserver               0x0003fc22 mach_port_callback + 78
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x9119ed0a __CFMachPortPerform + 346
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x9119eb91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 49
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x9119e7bb __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 155
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x911d7e01 __CFRunLoopRun + 2193
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x911d71dc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 332
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x911e7f01 CFRunLoopRun + 129
    15  XPCService                          0x905501ac xpc_service_main + 461
    16  com.apple.qtkitserver               0x0002acde main + 158
    17  com.apple.qtkitserver               0x00015a11 start + 53
)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x912e1957 ___TERMINATING_DUE_TO_UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION___ + 7
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x965a1149 objc_exception_throw + 155
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x911d727d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 493
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x911e7f01 CFRunLoopRun + 129
4   com.apple.XPCService            0x905501ac xpc_service_main + 461
5   com.apple.qtkitserver           0x0002acde main + 158
6   com.apple.qtkitserver           0x00015a11 start + 53
```